# Getting null in queryresult

Tags: azure, api, asp.net-core

I have created .Net core Api with Azure table storage.I am using following code to fetch all records with Partionkey 'New' but I am getting null in queryResult.

```
TableOperation q;
TableQuery<customer> query = new TableQuery<customer>()
.Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "New"));
var queryResult = cloudTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query,new TableContinuationToken());
```

Please suggest.

Tried other options like

```
TableOperation retrrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<customer>("New",*);
var queryResult = cloudTable.ExecuteAsync(retrrieveOperation).Result;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ran your code and `ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync` method works just fine for me. Here's the code I wrote:

```
        var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
        var tableClient = account.CreateCloudTableClient();
        var table = tableClient.GetTableReference("Test");
        table.CreateIfNotExists();
        TableQuery<DynamicTableEntity> query = new TableQuery<DynamicTableEntity>()
            .Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "New"));
        var queryResult = table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, new TableContinuationToken()).Result;
```

---

Regarding `TableOperation.Retrieve`, it is only intended to retrieve a single entity based on the `partition key` and `row key` value and will return `null` if no matching entity found that matches the `partition key` and `row key` combination.

```
        TableOperation retrrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<DynamicTableEntity>("New", "");
        var queryResult1 = table.ExecuteAsync(retrrieveOperation).Result;
```